# Is there a way to force a table value to be 0 on all updates unless explicitly stated otherwise?

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-update

I have a SQL table that includes various log entries that must be acknowledged by a user. To facilitate this, there is a trigger on `UPDATE` or `INSERT` for the table that creates entries in another table whenever a log entry is added or changed. It worked well until recently when it was decided that in all cases but one (one for now... this might change in the future), the trigger would fire normally. In one case, specifically for rejecting the progress of escalating a log entry, it needs to act differently.

We want to retain that trigger since there are large number of places where we update the table by directly inserting or updating a value in it. After much wrestling with possibilities, the decision was made to attack one more value for a log entry, a bit indicating whether we want the trigger to fire "normally" or in the special case, an imperfect approach, but one which seemed the least harmful of scenarios.

Unfortunately, as I've sat down to implement it, Fridge Logic has kicked in. It's no problem to explicitly set the bit in that one case. But, of course, we don't want to retain it once we processed this especially, and changing the bit would count as an update that would fire the trigger again.

So, long story short, is there a way to set up a table so that, upon an insert or update, if no value is specified, it defaults to a safe value of not doing the special trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEFAULT CONSTRAINT for inserts but for update you will need a trigger

something like .....

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_set_Defaults 
ON dbo.SomeTable
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE t
     SET t.Col1 = 0
    FROM dbo.SomeTable t
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON T.PK_Column = i.PK_Column
    WHERE i.Col1 IS NULL    --<-- Columns of intrest 

END
```

Comment: I didn't know about the COALESCE function. It's only one value where I need to act differently if it's not specified. So, before the extant trigger, I would run this one so that, unless specified, the bypass bit would be 0?

Comment: I have updated my answer, if it is only one column then it makes your trigger very simple, have a look at the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default to a column using this.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT SomeValue FOR MyColumn;
```